# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition working locally but not when deployed

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, google-maps, heroku, geolocation

I have a ReactJS app working locally that only gets out of the loading screen when the user allows location permissions, when I open it locally it asks the permissions and the app starts working, but i have deployed to AWS Amplify and Heroku and in both the app just doesn't ask for the permissions, staying in the loading screen forever. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more information here (including sample code and/or deployment configuration)?

Comment: Hi, the part of the code that asks for the location looks like this:
`async componentDidMount(){
    const response = await api.get('hospital')
    const data = response.data;
 
    this.setState({markers: data})
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        this.setState({initialPosX: latitude})
        this.setState({initialPosY: longitude})
        this.setState({gotPos: true})

      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
}`

Comment: did you ever resolve this. facing simlar challenge